# click on selected element in drop down menu with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to select the second element from a drop down menu using selenium, as you can see in the screenshot, the selection seems almost completed, but then I didn't manage to confirm the change. I tried using click() or Keys.ENTER but nothing.

here is the HTML:

```
<div class="mainSelectParent">
    <div class="styled-select" style="">
       <label></label>
       <select id="mainselect" style="display: none;">
        <option value="agency">une agence</option>
        <option value="atm">un distributeur automatique de billets</option>
        <option value="atmCashDeposit">un automate de dépôt de billets</option>
       </select><div class="ms-parent" style="width: 100%;"><button type="button" class="ms-choice"><span class=""> un distributeur automatique de billets</span><div class="open"></div></button><div class="ms-drop bottom" style="display: block;"><ul style="max-height: 250px;"><li class=""><label><input type="radio" name="selectItem" checked="checked" value="agency"> une agence</label></li><li class="selected"><label><input type="radio" name="selectItem" value="atm"> un distributeur automatique de billets</label></li><li><label><input type="radio" name="selectItem" value="atmCashDeposit"> un automate de dépôt de billets</label></li><li class="ms-no-results" style="display: none;">No matches found</li></ul></div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

and here is my code:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,    "mainSelectParent")))
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name('mainSelectParent')
element.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
element.click()
```

I also tried using Select and ActionChains but no better luck.

Comment: I see no element with `class='mainSelectParent'` in provided `HTML` sample on which you're trying to click

Comment: I added more html to include the mainSelectParent class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attribute `style="display: none;"` under `<select>` tag is causing problem to select the dropdown value.

Solution :- First you need to change the attribute value(make is display) then have to select the dropdown. You have to use `JavascriptExecutor` to do that in following way -

In Java -

```
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("document.getElementById('mainselect').setAttribute('style', 'display:block')");
```

In Python following code may work (Please use `JavascriptExecuter` according to `Python` language)

```
        driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('mainselect').setAttribute('style', 'display:block')");

        select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('mainselect'))

        # select by visible text
        select.select_by_visible_text('un distributeur automatique de billets')

        # OR

        # select by value 
        select.select_by_value('atm')

        # OR
        # select by index
        select.select_by_index(1)
```

Comment: that's exactly what I needed, thanks for that! I added a loop and now I get all the links! cheers

Comment: nice to hear you. enjoy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Select` class to work with dropdown constrains,

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

select = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('mainselect'))

# select by visible text
select.select_by_visible_text('un distributeur automatique de billets')

# OR

# select by value 
select.select_by_value('atm')

# OR
# select by index
select.select_by_index(1)
```

More about Select class, please refer [this](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/navigating.html#filling-in-forms).

Comment: I had already tried but I got "Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with". That's when I added select = Select(ActionChains(driver.find_element_by_id('mainselect'))) getting the error 'ActionChains' object has no attribute 'tag_name'